# Business layer: Looking for a complete reference?

Tags: business-logic, business-objects, business-logic-layer

I'm studying business layer and need a complete reference which covers issues about "how to manage dependency between business layer and other layers",  "how many ways are there to send data between layers"  and most important for me "how to group business logic and make business component and talk about possible ways....".

do you know any reference?

EDIT:
I would be delighted if you introduce some e-book for it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

the best (in my opinion) approaches to decoupling layers it to use a message passing metaphor. This way communication between the layers is done with messages that are types that contain information only pertinent to the communication. These light weight types are then interpreted by each layer as they see fit.

In essence don't pass things that are not needed. If both layers need a piece of information then there is a high likely hood that some other entity should be brokering access to that information (for example persisted data in db).

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

[Three-Layered Services Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff648105(v=pandp.10))

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC71978.gif))</sub>

and

[Layered Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff650258(v=pandp.10))

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider reading these books.

[image]

[image]
<sub>(source: [infibeam.com](http://img.infibeam.com/img/a3c437df/218/6/9780735626218.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I recently stumbled onto this one and found it to be a great read (free ebook in PDF, or read it in MSDN), got the printed version on Amazon shortly after.

Microsoft Patterns & Practices Application Architecture Guide 2.0 -
http://apparchguide.codeplex.com/

EDIT: Here's the section on Business Layers in the MSDN version: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658103%28v=PandP.10%29.aspx